# How to nicely format my console/terminal text as HTML

Tags: html, jakarta-ee

I have a java program which sends a results (as seen in a console) via HTTP to a browser. The real results are nicely formatted by tabs and newlines, as seen below:

```
./src/yse4    : The YSE emulator in use
[-w]          - [w]rap around at tracefile end and begin anew at time zero.
[-f filename] - [-f tracefile to use from]
/home/Downloads/yse.wzt/tracefiles/capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001.txt
    File name:  tracefiles/capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001.txt
    200     Forwarding Delay (ms)
    200     Reversed Delay (ms)
    3000000     Download Capacity (Mbps)
    3000000     Upload Capacity (Mbps)
    0.0001      Packet Error Rate (PER)
at=eth1
an=eth0
```

But when I send it as HTML, of course it does not recognize tabs and newlines. I manually add `<br>` at the end of each line, but still tabs are missing, and the browser shows it as below:

```
./src/yse4 : The YSE emulator in use 
[-w] - [w]rap around at tracefile end and begin anew at time zero. 
[-f filename] - [-f tracefile to use from] 
/home/Downloads/yse.wzt/tracefiles/capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001.txt 
 File name: tracefiles/capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001.txt 
 200 Forwarding Delay (ms) 
 200 Reversed Delay (ms) 
 3000000 Download Capacity (Mbps) 
 3000000 Upload Capacity (Mbps) 
 0.0001 Packet Error Rate (PER) 
at=eth1 
an=eth0
```

How can I format it as HTML to be seen nicely? Maybe any library exists for that?

Comment: How about `<pre></pre>`?

Comment: or wrap in a div with CSS - `white-space: pre;`

Comment: yeah, I forgot about `<pre>`! It works :) But the fon't is not an HTML default font; looks cody; a bit weird inside a web browser.

Comment: Have you checked this link: http://tohtml.com/ that might be useful. The other thing that might be useful is a javascript syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an HTML Table containing two rows and format the table as you want

[HTML Table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)